# Joining tables using foreign key

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables , employees and departments.

departments(id, department)

employees(id, department_id, name, and a bunch more here)

so employees.department_id is a foreign key to departments.id.

I need to show the table employees, but instead of department_id (showing the IDs of the departments) I need to show the actual departments name, so in place of department_id, i need to place departments.department.

How should I do this?

Comment: The answers all show INNER JOINs, not foreign keys. What is the difference?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your friend told you the truth :p

You just have to use a inner join between your two tables like this:

```
SELECT d.name, e.name, e.email, ... FROM deparments d INNER JOIN employees e ON d.id = e.department_id.
```

You have to adapt your field to have the desired output :)

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT employees.id, employees.department_id, employees.name, departments.department
FROM employees
INNER JOIN departments ON employees.department_id = departments.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `SELECT *` and just take the fields you really want if it's only to take a screenshot of the table values.

Like `SELECT department.name`

Answer (score 0):

This should cover it for you:

```
SELECT
    E.Id
    , D.Department
    , E.Name
    -- More stuff
FROM Employees E
INNER JOIN Departments D
    ON D.id = E.department_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT employees.*, department.department
FROM employees
INNER JOIN department ON employees.department_id = department.id
```